# React Native: Cannot find module 'react-native-svg' from 'BoxShadow.js'

Tags: css, react-native, react-native-svg

After installing the package `react-native-shadow` to do box shadows in react native, I am getting the error:

```
Cannot find module 'react-native-svg' from 'BoxShadow.js'
```

Answer (score 0):

After going to the [package's official site](https://github.com/879479119/react-native-shadow), I see they wrote:

> There are many users who are using different verion of react and
> react-native, so we have removed the dependency of react-native-svg in
> package.json since 1.1.3, and you must add the correct version of
> react-native-svg as they suggested. :sorry:

So you must manually add it to your own project:

```
yarn add react-native-svg
```